# Function call on slider release?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

I use a slider to load historical data into my visualization application.  The slider represents a period in time relative to now.  So you can slide backwards in time and it will load data.

Currently, however, the data will load whenever the value of the slider changes which means if I want to see 5 hours ago?  I have to load everything in between...

The code I am using is listed below:

```
    history = LoadData.Historical();

    data = GameObject.Find("DataManager").GetComponent<LoadData>();

    slider.maxValue = history.Length - 1;
    slider.value = slider.maxValue;
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ValueChange(); });
```

where ValueChange() contains something like this:

```
    LoadData.Candles(data.bounds, history[(int)slider.value]);
```

Is there a way that I can only load the data when the value has been changed AND when I am not holding the slider?

Note: I have tried a coroutine method to achieve this, but it only ended in tears and infinite loops. :/

Edit:

I drafted this solution, but it seems OnMouseUp does not work directly on Sliders... Any ideas?

```
void Start()
{

    slider = gameObject.GetComponent<Slider>();

    history = LoadData.Historical();

    data = GameObject.Find("DataManager").GetComponent<LoadData>();

    slider.maxValue = history.Length - 1;
    slider.value = slider.maxValue;
    slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate { ValueChange(); });

    LoadData.Candles(data.bounds, history[(int)slider.maxValue]);

    valueChanged = false;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    Debug.Log("UP");
    if (valueChanged)
    {
        LoadData.DestroyCandles();
        LoadData.Candles(data.bounds, history[(int)slider.value]);
    }
    valueChanged = false;
}

void ValueChange()
{
    valueChanged = true;
    Debug.Log(valueChanged);
}
```

Edit2:

[image]

Comment: You only want stuff to happen when you move the slider and then release it? Not just when you move it?

Comment: BTW why use a complicated "AddListener" call?  Just **drag the function to the slider in the Editor**.

Comment: well, releasing the slider means releasing the mouse button ............

Comment: Yes, only when the slider is released and has changed value.

I do understand what it means.  I tried to use coroutines to wait for the mouse to be released and stop and restart every value change, but it broke pretty quickly.

Comment: Joe, I prefer to do things through scripting when I can.  Is there any real difference between what I did and what you're suggesting?

Comment: what you need to coroutine for when an event fires on mouse up anway? just let your slider do its slider business and if you release the mouse and the slider value changed then laod your things?

Comment: So you're saying to track the value change manually and run that check on every mouse up?  Seems a little wasteful when onValueChanged exists.

Comment: Yes, both result in the same thing, but in one case, it checks less frequently.

Comment: no do the value changed business on value changed and the mouse up business on mouse up. in the end its 2 different things.

Comment: But it's one thing.  The event must only occur when both are true.  The only way to do this would be to set a bool when the value is changed and on mouse up, load if the bool is set.  However, it seems OnMouseUp() won't work here either...  See my edit above.

Comment: its OnPointerUp for UI elements (actually the EventSystem behind it). slider implements IPointerUpHandler

Comment: Neither seem to work... I added an image of my Object during play to my original post.

Comment: yes sorry, my bad, ofc you cant just register to the event. you need to implement IPointerUpHandler in your script (which isnt more than the OnPointerUp function really). the interface is part of UnityEngine.EventSystems

Comment: So I added "using UnityEngine.EventSystems;"  and still nothing.  The slider moves and sets my bool, but OnPointerUp() never runs.

Comment: I implemented it very naively using 

if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) { ThisWillWork(); }

where ThisWIllWork() is just a renamed OnPointerUp().

It works for now, but if you have any insight into this, I'd be very appreciative.  Also, thanks for looking into this with me @yes.

Comment: @AndersHokinson wrote you a short example of what i meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the event system to capture the MouseUp event like below. It should do the trick, but you will need to account for if the value changed or not yourself (just store the old value and check if its not equal)

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

    public class SliderOnPointerUpExample : MonoBehaviour, IPointerUpHandler {

        Slider slider;
        float oldValue;

        void Start() {
            slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
            oldValue = slider.value;
        }

        public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData) {
            if(slider.value != oldValue) {
                Debug.Log("Slider value changed from " + oldValue + " to " + slider.value);
                oldValue = slider.value;
            }
        }
    }
```

idk if its the best solution, a solution nevertheless (but probably not the worst either) :D

Comment: Unit had me include ((IPointerUpHandler)slider).OnPointerUp(eventData); inside of OnPointerUp(), but otherwise, this works nicely.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: that should be no requirement. if you want i can read over your new code if you paste it somewhere ... otherwise, you are welcome, glad i could be of help :)